# In flutter how to prevent screenshot to secure my app for android part in kotlin

Tags: flutter, kotlin

In my flutter app, it supports the kotlin for android part. i can't find a code to prevent the screeenshot in app which is written in kotlin language. I searched over the google then i found the code that is written in java language but i require the kotlin code to prevent the screenshot.

```
package com.example.schoolbells

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import android.os.Bundle; 
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);

}

}
```

getting this error in onCreate method

> [ERROR] :Unresolved reference: WindowManagerkotlin(UNRESOLVED_REFERENCE)

I tried this code in kotlin but getting error.
Is there any other way to prevent screenshot in flutter?

Comment: What is your error

Comment: i can't able to write a code in kotlin to prevent the screenshot

Comment: can you suggest me how can i do it

Comment: No dude, edit your question to include the error your application is throwing...

Comment: "getting error" is not specific enough for anyone to be able to help you. Please provide more detail, either the compiler message if it's a compilation error, or the exception stacktrace if it's a runtime error.

Comment: i edited the question please check it now

Comment: put `LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE`, remove the WindowManager., You've added import for that